# Contagem de Resultados na BD para paginação

Tags: php, sql-server

Estou com um problema, eu quero saber quantos dados existem na Base de Dados, mas com este código está a retornar **-1** já utilizei este código para outros trabalhos (só que com mysql), neste caso é com SQL Server

```
$pag = (isset($_GET['pag'])) ? strip_tags((int)$_GET['pag']) : '1';

                                $maximo = '6';//produtos por pagina

                                $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM cl");
                                $stmt2->execute();
                                $totalRegistros2 = $stmt2->rowCount();
                                $paginas2 = ceil($totalRegistros2/$maximo);

                                if(isset($_GET['pag'])){
                                    if (($_GET['pag']>$paginas2)||($_GET['pag']<1)){
                                        $pag=1;
                                    }
                                }

                                $inicio = ($pag * $maximo) - $maximo;
                        echo $totalRegistros2;
                        echo $count;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui fica direitinho com PDO

```
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT count(*) AS total_records FROM cl");
$stmt2->execute(); 
$total_records = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['total_records'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Da documentação do PHP em relação à função [rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was
>   a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows
>   returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed
>   for all databases and should not be relied on for portable
>   applications.

Se a última instrução for um SELECT não é garantido que o rowCount() devolva o número de registos. Depende do SGBD.

Se queres saber o número total de registos podes sempre fazer

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) AS total_records FROM cl";
$rs_result = $db_connection->query($sql);
$total_records = $rs_result->fetch_assoc()['total_records'];
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar `SELECT count(*) FROM cl` para saber quantas linhas/registros essa tabela possui.